# Why Eclipse ADT layout is so difficult to use?

Tags: android, eclipse

I make an Android application. And put some buttons and a progressbar on the layout. But it is very difficult to adjust those componentss' position. They will move to some where wild when I drag them. I don't know whether other persons have met the same problem.
And what I cannot understand is that when I finish relayouting the components, I found that button1 now has function of button2, and button2 has function of button3... Who met the same problem? And could you let me know why and your solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difficilty of somethink can't be easely comparable. It depends of a big number of elements and one of the most important is your expertise. If you are used to something and then you will sudenly change to something complitely different, you will find this difficult to use, even if it is easier in general.

In which concerns the android ADT layout, I agree with you that the grafical interface is not great to use (especially if you are comming from iPhone).

I can suggest you to use directly XML and use the graphical interface for only basic things like creating your button, texts etc.

Using XML, it will be a litle bit difficult on the begining but once you are familiarized with, you can push the limits higher.

I don't know if this can help but it is my point of view. (+1 dor you, interesting question).

Answer (score 1):

Graphical Layout sometimes behaves unpredictably. My solution is to use Outline on the right pane in the screen and set all the paramters manually instead of using 'drag and drop method'.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Marcin that the drag-and-drop editor can occasionally behave in an unexpected manner.  I usually use it to achieve a rough layout and then fine tune in the xml.

Included for reference - Android docs for creating input controls in xml:

> http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls.html

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with Tom Hard was before when we did not have one layout pluggin in Eclipse and had to write all the layouts by hand.
What actually happens is that there are still many bugs in the ADT.

My advice is studying hard the layouts and when a error occur edit them via code.